# How to Increase the result list in jquery.textcomplete.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using  `jquery.textcomplete.js` for my project but `jquery.textcomplete.js` is generating only 5 list because of this I am not able to select my correct word. Please let me know how to increase the list size from 5 to 10 or more.

Another problem if my word has space, for example, "Close End Account Details" then I can't get it when I hit space after writing "Close" in my text area. Please help me to get rid of this.

Below is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        var obj = [];
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model.WholeList)
            {

            @:obj.push('@item.Text');
                               }
    }
        $('#mytext').textcomplete([
       {
           words: obj,
           match: /\b(\w{1,})$/,
           maxCount :10,
           search: function (term, callback) {
               callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {
                   return word.search(new RegExp(term, "i")) == 0 ? word : null;
               }));
           },
           index: 1,
           replace: function (word) {
               return ' ' + word + ' ' + ' ';
           }
       }
        ]);
    }
    catch (Exception) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote ? That way we will help you in a better way. You can also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, tried some examples that did not work and ended up cutting the problem from it's root.

At some point in the 'jquery.textcomplete.js' library, you should find a line that sets the variable to 10 (it is the default value)

```
maxCount:10
```

Change this to whatever you want and you should be fine.

*BONUS*: If you are aiming to have many entries in the dropdown list, you will probably want to apply these css rules to the element:

```
max-height: 300px; [or-any-other-value]
overflow-Y: auto;
```

in order to avoid having you window going out of bounds.

---

**CAUTION:**

This solution should be your last resort since it has some serious disadvantages:

1. It is not dynamic
2. Will be lost if you re-import the file, or update your jquery library.

If you find the proper way of setting the maxCount variable please share it here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add maxCount: 10 or what ever number you want to the initialization, as shown below:

```
('textarea.content').textcomplete([
{ // html
    match: /<(\w*)$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        callback($.map(elements, function (element) {
            return element.indexOf(term) === 0 ? element : null;
        }));
    },
    index: 1,
    replace: function (element) {
        return ['<' + element + '>', '</' + element + '>'];
    }
},
{ // Model properties
    id: 'availableModelNames',
    words: availableTags,
    match: /\@Model.(\w*)$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {
            return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
        }));
    },
    index: 1,
    replace: function (word) {
        return '@Model.' + word;
    }
}
], {
    onKeydown: function (e, commands) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 74) { // CTRL-J
            return commands.KEY_ENTER;
        }
    },
    maxCount: 10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [docs](https://github.com/yuku/textcomplete/blob/master/doc/api.md#textcompleteoptions) for the Textcomplete object's options (TextcompleteOptions) you can see that there's a property called `dropdown` with type [`DropdownOptions`](https://github.com/yuku/textcomplete/blob/master/doc/api.md#dropdownoptions).

One of the properties of `DropdownOptions` is `maxCount` which is what we're looking for here. This property takes in a number.

Below I show setting the `maxCount` to be 100 after initializing a `Textcomplete` object:

```
var textcomplete = new Textcomplete(new Textcomplete.editors.Textarea(this));

textcomplete.dropdown.maxCount = 100;
```